# Mailing Reports aren't being received, even though they are shown as complete and delivered successfully

Tags: civimail

Monthly Newsletter was prepared and submitted for mailing correctly in CiviCRM.  The mailing was scheduled, completed, and delivered successfully, per the CiviCRM mailing status report.  However, the Monthly Newsletter report has not actually been received by the targeted individuals.

What would cause this to happen?  How can we fix it?

Comment: Can you check if its under spam or junk folder in your mail box?

Comment: Are other mailings working? Try a small test mail.

Comment: Can you check the website's email delivery logs? For example, in Cpanel you can track the delivery of emails and, on failure statuses, gives you a reason why the email didn't send.